# Preserving Antiquine for Antiquity

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[This question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/49002/write-an-antiquine) clearly has problems, as highlighted in the comments, but seems to be an interesting idea. Maybe we could have some suggestions on ways to improve it so the idea isn't lost?

Answer (score 2):

**Remove the modified antiquine option**, as answers that are not a true antiquine will otherwise clutter and confuse things. All answers should output only valid programs, not just arbitrary strings of characters.

Answer (score 2):

**Remove the requirement for a minimum length of 20 characters**. The requirement that there be at least 2 other valid programs of the same length is sufficient to close the loophole. A minimum length is not ideal for a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) question.

*(Requiring at least 2 other valid programs imposes a minimum length of 1 character, but that seems reasonable...)*